# PTRACE_SYSCALL and orig_eax

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls, ptrace

I want to kill a child process if it does other system calls than read and write (and even filter these calls as well, but it's a different story) but there some system calls done by default.

I have compiled an empty test child (exits instantly) program and I also have a parent process which forks, enables ptracing and executes the child program. Parent process uses PTRACE_SYSCALL and checks orig_eax every time. My test program reports that the child was stopped 49 times (which, I assume, means 48 / 2 + 1 system calls).

I wanted to know whether the system calls sequence is always the same (initialization) and/or it's possible to know when I can start and when to stop kill-on-syscall in my parent?

Comment: I am not able to clearly understand what did you  mean by the same sequence? It depends on the child process. By the way did you check out [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) 
You can see what all system calls are called by strace [your child process] I hope i can be of some help to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem once (see [my question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343058/preventing-processes-to-execute-certain-system-calls)). When a program starts, it executes a lot of system calls when initializing the application (such as loading shared libraries) before calling `main()`. What I did is to simply allow somewhat more system calls and use another means of security (such as `chroot`) to prevent the application from accessing undesired files.

A better option would be to somehow find the entry point of the `main()` function of the program (see [this tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6210) for writing debugging code) and disable system calls after that point. I don't know if it's possible to do in general case, but that's the way I would start to search.

After finding the entry point, there is another way of restricting the program from making certain system calls. Instead of using `PTRACE_SYSCALL` to check each system call done by the program, inject a [`prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, ...)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/prctl.2.html) call to the program (using `ptrace()`) then just leave the program running.

Comment: Agreed, `PR_SET_SECCOMP` is the way to go.