# How process detect i'm using process_vm_readv on it's process?

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, memory

In android as a **root** user I'm trying to read another process memory by calling `process_vm_readv` function, The function itself work well but target process detects I'm reading it's process and will kill itself after a short delay.

> How the target process detect I'm using that function ?
>
> How to avoid target process to detect me when I'm using that function ?

This is what I use: https://gist.github.com/FergusInLondon/fec6aebabc3c9e61e284983618f40730

Comment: Maybe you can find something helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343058/preventing-processes-to-execute-certain-system-calls .